# Finding an equation for a vector that contains multiple points?

Tags: vector-spaces

How do I find an equation for a vector that contains the points $(\neg4,\neg4,6)$ and $(\neg2,\neg11,6)$. Someone told me that it should be in the form $Vector_1 + t\times Vector_2$. Where $t$ is a constant.I am not sure if that is correct.

**How do I find an equation for the vector that contains those two points?**

Answer (score 2):

A vector can not contain any points. To simplify you can think of a vector as a direction with a size. In the same way that a direction doesn't contain points neither does a vector.

What you are most probably thinking of is 3 dimensional affine linear space with a vector space associated to it. In that case you can find a line which contains two points and that line can be written in the form of a point + a parameter* a vector. Note the parameter is very much non constant instead it is essentially a variable spanning all of $\mathbb{R}$. Just think of it

This might look similar to a vector plus a constant times a vector in that quite often both points and vectors will be written as $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ for $a_i\in \mathbb{R}$.

To actually find the appropriate point and vector making up your line consider that you already know two points on the line. You can choose one to be your base point $P$ and then find a vector $v$ such that $P+v=Q$ where B is your second point.

Comment: @Chiwda Have you ever studied abstract vector spaces? The flag is dismissed.